# Это прямая речь?

Tags: прямая-речь, цитата, несобственно-прямая-речь

Как писал Иванов, "вторая книга Петрова была составлена в 1980 г. Затем переиздана в 1990 г.".
Надо ли оформлять цитату как прямую речь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Цитаты заключаются в кавычки и оформляются знаками препинания так же, как прямая речь.
[Знаки препинания при цитатах](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139#pp139)

Прямая речь **не выделяется** кавычками, если прямое указание на источник сообщения оформлено как вводная конструкция:
*Статья ученого, **сообщает критик**, вызвала большой интерес общественности.*
[Знаки препинания при прямой речи. § 136. Примечание](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138)

Мне кажется, что слова *Как писал Иванов* можно считать вводной частью, — в этом случае кавычки не требуются.
Думаю, что вполне возможно оформить предложение таким образом:
**Вторая книга Петрова была составлена в 1980 г., как писал Иванов, затем переиздана в 1990 г.**

Answer (score 2):

Вариант редактирования:

**Как писал Иванов, вторая книга Петрова была составлена в 1980 г.,  а затем переиздана в 1990 г.**

В таких предложениях нет необходимости в использовании дословного цитирования и оформлении прямой речи по классическому образцу.

*Как писал Иванов*  — вводное предложение указывает на источник информации.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно ли? Нет, вы не обязаны. Можно ли? Есть подобные примеры в Нацкорпусе, хотя я бы предпочел после "как писал" не ставить прямую речь.